# Retrieving data from excel by Fillio API it gives error

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-poi

```
package com.excel.reader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import com.codoid.products.exception.FilloException;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Fillo;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Recordset;

public class ReaderApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
            Connection connection = fillo
                    .getConnection("E:\\Projects\\POC\\Documents\\Optima\\Docs\\Optima_Other.xlsx");
            String strQuery = "Select * from Optima_Data where Property='Holiday Inn Express London - Wandsworth'";
            Recordset recordset = connection.executeQuery(strQuery);
            while (recordset.next()) {
                System.out.println(recordset.getField("Rate"));
            }
        } catch (FilloException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

While running this code it give following exception on connection statement.

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/impl/CTWorksheetImpl$1ColsList
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl.getColsList(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.cleanColumns(ColumnHelper.java:57)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.<init>(ColumnHelper.java:50)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:194)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:180)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:300)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:200)
at com.codoid.products.fillo.Fillo.getWorkbook(Fillo.java:59)
at com.codoid.products.fillo.Fillo.getConnection(Fillo.java:40)
at com.excel.reader.ReaderApi.main(ReaderApi.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl$1ColsList
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 11 more
```

I also tried using JDBC:

```
package com.excel.reader;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ExcelDB {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};"
                        + "Dbq=E:\\Projects\\POC\\Documents\\Optima\\Docs\\Optima_Data.xlsm;");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SN,IR FROM [Sheet1$]");

        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("AllTXN_Issued"));
            }
        }
        rs.close();

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

This also gives a class not found exception.

1. The size of excel is huge like 75000-100000 of records containing many columns and sheets. I have to fetch the data from it and compare to the UI.
2. I also tried Apache POI for retrieving the data but storing huge data and processing it for getting expected value also seems difficult.

Note: Is there any better approach to do it? Please suggest.

Comment: You seem to be missing a dependency: _"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl$1ColsList"_

Comment: The JDBC part doesn't work because the JdbcOdbcDriver was removed in Java 8.

Comment: Did you [try following the instructions in the Apache POI FAQ entry for this](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)? If not, why not? And what happens when you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to some java versioning or Eclipse configuration issue. So closing the question.